# Return related eloquent models altogether in json format

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent

I'm learning Eloquent Model Relationships in Laravel. In my demo project I have two tables `Sets` and `Cards`, they have `One to many` relationship. One `Set` has many `Cards` and a `Card` belongs to a `Set`.

I want the output to hold both `Sets` and `Cards` together in nested `JSON` array, `Cards` under `Sets`. I have set the relationships in both models.

**My expected result**

```
[
  {
    "set_id":1,
    "name":"English",
    "description":"English Language",
    "created_at":"2020-03-31T15:41:55.000000Z",
    "updated_at":"2020-03-31T15:41:55.000000Z"},
    "cards: 
       {
          "card_id":1,
          "name":"Greetings",
          "description":"Greetings related questions",
          "set_id":1,
          "created_at":"2020-03-31T15:45:03.000000Z",
          "updated_at":"2020-03-31T15:45:03.000000Z"
       }
  }
]
```

**Set.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;
use App\Card;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Set extends Model
{
    protected $table = "sets";

    public function cards() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Card');
    }
}
```

**Card.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Set;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Card extends Model
{
    protected $table = "cards";

    public function sets() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Set');
    }
}
```

In my `Controller` I have tried to get my result by this line `return Set::all()->cards;`, but it says `Property [cards] does not exist on this collection instance.` My migration files have foreign key set in `Cards` table, so I think the relationship between tables is made correctly or maybe I'm wrong.

I have read the detailed Laravel Doc for Eloquent Relationships, but did not find any query that returns related models together in a nested `JSON`, the way I'm expecting.

Comment: Check out this syntax: `Set::with('cards')->get()`. Its documented here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Thank you very much. My bad, I missed it.